# Count tables in H2 Database with OrmLite

Tags: java, h2, ormlite

Is there any way to get the number of tables in a h2 database when using OrmLite?

I'm looking for something like:

```
mysql> show tables;
```

for OrmLite.

Comment: I just verified, you can actually run this query in the H2 database. So I guess, the question is, how can you execute native SQL statements using OrmLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the number of tables in a h2 database when using OrmLite?

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) has a pretty good online manual.  If you have looked in the index under "raw queries" you would have found the following:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries

There is a lot of detail there but you can do something like the following using the [`Dao.queryRaw(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29).

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> results = dao.queryRaw("show tables;");
```